# Both Public and Private DNS not working. How make it work properly without any conflict

Tags: dns, dhcp, dynamic-dns, dhcp-server

I setup private network so I installed DHCP in one of my server. Now my public network DNS is not working. How can I setup DNS for private network with conflict the public network DNS?

#### DHCP Setup.

Install the DHCP server and configure it:

```
apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

Select the network card on which your  server will be listen for dhcp requests

```
vi /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server

INTERFACES="eth0"
```

Change the DHCP configurations to specify the range of IP address to allocate to DHCP requests, etc.

```
vi /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

subnet 10.10.7.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.10.7.30 10.10.7.254;
  option domain-name-servers 10.10.7.1;
  option domain-name "opexlabs-demo.org";
  option routers 10.10.7.1;
}
```

Restart the DHCP server service:

```
service isc-dhcp-server restart
/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart
```

Then I setup DNS for the private network:

#### DNS Setup.

Install the dns package

```
apt-get install bind9
```

Generate a shared key so that BIND will accept changes

```
rndc-confgen -a -c dhcpd.key -k dhcpd
```

We are creating zones. Zones are generally domain names or subnets

```
vi /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/dhcpd.key"
zone "opexlabs-demo.org" {
    type master;
    file "/var/cache/bind/opexlabs-demo.org.zone";
    allow-update { key "dhcpd"; };
 };

zone "7.10.10.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/var/cache/bind/10.10.7.zone";
    allow-update { key "dhcpd"; };

 };
```

Change the user and group to access:

```
chown bind dhcpd.key
chown bind /var/cache/bind/*
chown bind.dhcpd dhcpd.key 
chmod g+r dhcpd.key
```

Apparmor default configuration to allow DHCPD to read a file:

```
vi /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.dhcpd

/etc/bind/dhcpd.key r,
```

Restart the apparmor service:

```
/etc/init.d/apparmor restart
```

Finally setup DNS in DHCP

```
vi /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

ddns-update-style interim;
include "/etc/bind/dhcpd.key";
authoritative;

subnet 10.10.7.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.10.7.30 10.10.7.254;
  option domain-name-servers 10.10.7.1;
  option domain-name "opexlabs-demo.org";
  option routers 10.10.7.1;

  ddns-domainname "opexlabs-demo.org";
  zone opexlabs-demo.org. {
          primary 10.10.7.1;
          key     "dhcpd";
  }

  zone 7.10.10.in-addr.arpa. {
          primary 10.10.7.1;
          key     "dhcpd";
  }

}

/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart
/etc/init.d/bind9 restart
```

Actually we are using Public network (192.168.1.0/24) it have default dhcp and dns server. And I setup private dhcp in one of my server (10.192.1.0/24). Private Dhcp server working without any conflict with Public network. Now i want to setup DNS to private network. I configured in private dns in the server but after configured public network DNS not able to work. How can both DNS will work in system.

Comment: this is the link I followed. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jva46g4BLSg.

Comment: I have already Public network (10.192.1.0/24) with dns everything. When I installed and configured the dns in private network (10.10.7.0/24) the Public network dns not able to work.

Comment: i didnt say to u to watch the video

Comment: Actually we are using Public network (192.168.1.0/24) it have default dhcp and dns server.  And I setup private dhcp in one of my server (10.192.1.0/24). Private Dhcp server working without any conflict with Public network.

Now i want to setup DNS to private network. I configured in private dns in the server but after configured public network DNS not able to work. How can both DNS will work in system.

Comment: 192.168.1.0/24 is not public. You also mention 10.192.1.0/24 and 10.10.7.0/24, very confusing. What exactly is not working? Do you mean you can't resolve e.g. www.google.com from a system on your private network? If so, it's probably because you haven't enabled recursion in your DNS server for the private network; all the text above about DHCP, dynamic DNS updates etc. just confuse the issue.

Comment: Ok sorry. Private network 10.10.7.0/24 and Public network 10.192.1.0/24. Now tell how to setup dns for private network